# SQL Server return sub nodes (values) by querying parent node attribute name

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, attributes, nodes

I have the following problem: SQL database which I can't change. Table "LogEntries" with fields "ID" (autonumber) and "Details" (plain text).
The details field contains plain text entries as well as xml data.
Need to do a double cast or convert to turn "Details" into xml for the records I want.

XML structure is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<changes typeName="Document" name="005019 (0)" id="8567">
    <propertyChange name="OwnerPersonName" typeName="System.String" systemName="OwnerPersonID">
        <from id="541">Thomas, Marcus</from>
        <to id="103">Murphy, Tony</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <propertyChange name="AuthorPersonName" typeName="System.String" systemName="AuthorPersonID">
        <from id="10">Witten, Howard</from>
        <to id="750">Atukorala, Anu</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <propertyChange name="ReviewDateTime" typeName="System.DateTime">
        <from>2008-04-28T00:00:00</from>
        <to>2010-04-28T00:00:00</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <collectionChanges typeName="DocumentRelatedStandardsCollection" name="DocumentRelatedStandardsCollection">
        <addition typeName="DocumentRelatedStandard" name="Integrated Management System\Implementation\Quality\7.2 Customer related processes" id="239">
            <propertyChange name="StandardDescription" typeName="System.String">
                <from></from>
                <to>Integrated Management System\Implementation\Quality\7.2 Customer related processes</to>
            </propertyChange>
            <propertyChange name="StandardName" typeName="System.String">
                <from></from>
                <to>7.2 Customer related processes</to>
            </propertyChange>
        </addition>
    </collectionChanges>
</changes>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the child elements values of `<from>` and `<to>` for the `<propertyChange>` parent element where attribute `name = "ReviewDateTime"`.

Tried cross apply, direct access (cast cast value), etc. and keep getting errors. Last attempt seems to get me close, but it's telling me the sub nodes aren't there.

This is what I've got for cross apply:

```
    Select
            [QPulseAuditLog].dbo.LogEntries.ID as [LogId]
            ,t.c.value('/(to)[1]','nvarchar(10)') as [from]

FROM        [QPulseAuditLog].[dbo].[LogEntries]

cross apply (select cast(cast([Details] as ntext) as xml) where [QPulseAuditLog].[dbo].[LogEntries].[Details] LIKE '%ReviewDateTime%') as t0(x)
cross apply t0.x.nodes('/changes/propertyChange/@ReviewDateTime') t(c)
```

And this is the error:
*Msg 2256, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
XQuery [t0.x.value()]: Syntax error near '(', expected a "node test".*

This is what I've got for straight value access:

```
    use [QPulseAuditLog]

SELECT 
            ID
            [Details],
            CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(Ntext,[Details])).value('/changes/propertyChange/@ReviewDateTime/from[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS StatusChangeFrom


FROM        [QPulseAuditLog].[dbo].[LogEntries]
```

And this is the error:
Msg 2261, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
XQuery [value()]: There is no element named 'from' in the type 'attribute(ReviewDateTime,xdt:untypedAtomic) *'.

Option 2 is preferred as it makes things easier for me (NOT XML experienced at all). Any idea where I'm going wrong? Hoping it's my syntax. All help appreciated ... it's driving me up the wall.

Cheers
Bodo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full DDL and a working sample. It is better to treat XML as XML data type, and use *XQuery* to query it.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Details NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Details)
VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<changes typeName="Document" name="005019 (0)" id="8567">
    <propertyChange name="OwnerPersonName" typeName="System.String" systemName="OwnerPersonID">
        <from id="541">Thomas, Marcus</from>
        <to id="103">Murphy, Tony</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <propertyChange name="AuthorPersonName" typeName="System.String" systemName="AuthorPersonID">
        <from id="10">Witten, Howard</from>
        <to id="750">Atukorala, Anu</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <propertyChange name="ReviewDateTime" typeName="System.DateTime">
        <from>2008-04-28T00:00:00</from>
        <to>2010-04-28T00:00:00</to>
    </propertyChange>
    <collectionChanges typeName="DocumentRelatedStandardsCollection"
                       name="DocumentRelatedStandardsCollection">
        <addition typeName="DocumentRelatedStandard"
                  name="Integrated Management System\Implementation\Quality\7.2 Customer related processes"
                  id="239">
            <propertyChange name="StandardDescription" typeName="System.String">
                <from></from>
                <to>Integrated Management System\Implementation\Quality\7.2 Customer related processes</to>
            </propertyChange>
            <propertyChange name="StandardName" typeName="System.String">
                <from></from>
                <to>7.2 Customer related processes</to>
            </propertyChange>
        </addition>
    </collectionChanges>
</changes>'),
('Plain text');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *, TRY_CAST(CAST(Details AS NTEXT) AS XML) AS xml_data FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , col.value('(from/text())[1]','DATETIME') AS [From]
    , col.value('(to/text())[1]','DATETIME') AS [To]
FROM rs
      CROSS APPLY rs.[xml_Data].nodes('/changes/propertyChange[@name="ReviewDateTime"]') AS tab(col);
```

> Output

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| ID |          From           |           To            |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2008-04-28 00:00:00.000 | 2010-04-28 00:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to want to work ... except now I get the dreaded "XML parsing: line 4, character 32, illegal xml character" error. I swear, whoever designed that table should be punished ... severely.

Comment: Please share that "XML" with the problematic characters.

Comment: Well, I checked. Error message said Line 49, Character 40. There is no illegal character. Arrrrgh!!!

Comment: Line 49: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <changes typeName="Document" name="003826 (1)" id="7149">    <propertyChange name="AuthorPersonName" typeName="System.String" systemName="AuthorPersonID">      <from id="729">Hoppe, Peter</from>      <to id="839">Hone, Dianne</to>    </propertyChange>    <propertyChange name="ReviewDateTime" typeName="System.DateTime">      <from>2007-04-02T00:00:00</from>      <to>2010-08-07T00:00:00</to>    </propertyChange>  </changes>

Comment: What can I say. The provided XML is legit. It is possible that the issue is somewhere else. Possibly even a different row or Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V couldn't copy it.

Comment: It is possible you can identify that row by using this SQL: `SELECT *, TRY_CAST(Details AS XML) AS xml_data FROM @tbl;`